# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector'

Tags: javascript

```
function globalNavPopup(e) {
    var t = this,
        n = Strut.touch.isSupported ? "touchend" : "click";
    this.activeClass = "globalPopupActive", this.root = document.querySelector(e), this.link = this.root.querySelector(".rootLink"), this.popup = this.root.querySelector(".popup"), this.closeButton = this.root.querySelector(".popupCloseButton"), this.link.addEventListener(n, function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(), t.togglePopup()
    }), this.popup.addEventListener(n, function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
    }), this.closeButton && this.closeButton.addEventListener(n, function(e) {
        t.closeAllPopups()
    }), document.body.addEventListener(n, function(e) {
        Strut.touch.isDragging || t.closeAllPopups()
    }, !1)
}
```

This gives the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
    at new globalNavPopup (script.js:48)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:244)
```

Note: This is the pen I am trying to fix https://codepen.io/JakeHenshall/pen/ZBvLgG

Comment: You have `this.root.querySelector()` in three different places, so the error suggests that `this.root` is `null`, which in turn suggests that the value of `e` doesn't match anything that's in the page.

Comment: JLRishe is correct